# Accessing objects of other classes

Tags: java, class, object

I've recently picked up Java and have run into a problem. I have several files with different classes, but I can't figure out how I can access objects of the other classes in files other than the one they were declared in. For example:

```
player.java:
public class Player 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player();
    }
    public int getLocation()
    {
         return 2;
    }
}

monster.java:
public class Monster
{
    public void attackPlayer()
    {
        player.getLocation();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can access these objects of other classes effectively from other files and classes themselves? I know I could make the objects static and then access them as variables through the class they were made in, but that seems rather counter-intuitive? I come from a less object-oriented programming background so I'm still trying to understand java's style of programming.

Comment: Import them and use an instance of the object, like by passing one as a parameter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably just wanting something like this:

```
player.java:
public class Player 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player();
        Monster monster = new Monster();
        monster.attackPlayer(player);
    }
    public int getLocation()
    {
         return 2;
    }
}

monster.java:
public class Monster
{
    public void attackPlayer(Player player)
    {
        player.getLocation();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps/makes sense!

Comment: Thank you! Was exactly what I was trying to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start would be to pass in the player you want to attack "when" the monster attacks.

battle.java

```
public class Battle {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player player = new Player();
    Monster monster = new Monster();
    monster.attackPlayer(player);
  }
}
```

player.java:

```
public class Player 
{
    public int getLocation()
    {
         return 2;
    }
}
```

monster.java:

```
public class Monster
{
    public void attackPlayer(Player player)
    {
        player.getLocation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A class is just a blueprint for an object.

You can only call the methods defined in the Player class on an actual Player object, which you've instantiated - you've done this in the following line in the `main(String[] args)` method:

```
Player player = new Player();
```

However the `player` variable is now only available to code in the scope of its declaration - in this case, anywhere after this line in the `main(String[] args)` method.

It's not available outside of this scope. The `attackPlayer()` method in the Monster class is most definitely outside of this scope! When you reference `player` there, the compiler has no clue what that token refers to. You must pass in an argument of type Player, named `player` (or anything you like, really), to that method before you start to call methods on it.